# MapR installation failing for single node cluster

Tags: hadoop, installation, mapr

I was referring quick installation guide for single node cluster. For this i used 20GB storage file for MaprFS but while on installation , it is giving ' Unable to find disks: /maprfs/storagefile' .

Here is my configuration file.

```
# Each Node section can specify nodes in the following format
# Hostname: disk1, disk2, disk3
# Specifying disks is optional. If not provided, the installer will use the values of 'disks' from the Defaults section
[Control_Nodes]
maprlocal.td.td.com: /maprfs/storagefile
#control-node2.mydomain: /dev/disk3, /dev/disk9
#control-node3.mydomain: /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd
[Data_Nodes]
#data-node1.mydomain
#data-node2.mydomain: /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd
#data-node3.mydomain: /dev/sdd
#data-node4.mydomain: /dev/sdb, /dev/sdd
[Client_Nodes]
#client1.mydomain
#client2.mydomain
#client3.mydomain
[Options]
MapReduce1 = true
YARN = true
HBase = true
MapR-DB = true
ControlNodesAsDataNodes = true
WirelevelSecurity = false
LocalRepo = false
[Defaults]
ClusterName = my.cluster.com
User = mapr
Group = mapr
Password = mapr
UID = 2000
GID = 2000
Disks = /maprfs/storagefile
StripeWidth = 3
ForceFormat = false
CoreRepoURL = http://package.mapr.com/releases
EcoRepoURL = http://package.mapr.com/releases/ecosystem-4.x
Version = 4.0.2
MetricsDBHost =
MetricsDBUser =
MetricsDBPassword =
MetricsDBSchema =
```

Below is the error that i am getting.

```
2015-04-16 08:18:03,659 callbacks 42 [INFO]: Running task: [Verify Pre-Requisites]
2015-04-16 08:18:03,661 callbacks 87 [ERROR]: maprlocal.td.td.com: Unable to find disks: /maprfs/storagefile from /maprfs/storagefile remove disks: /dev/sda,/dev/sda1,/dev/sda2,/dev/sda3 and retry
2015-04-16 08:18:03,662 callbacks 91 [ERROR]: failed: [maprlocal.td.td.com] => {"failed": true}
2015-04-16 08:18:03,667 installrunner 199 [ERROR]: Host: maprlocal.td.td.com has 1 failures
2015-04-16 08:18:03,668 common 203 [ERROR]: Control Nodes have failures. Please fix the failures and re-run the installation. For more information refer to the installer log at /opt/mapr-installer/var/mapr-installer.log
```

Please help me here.

Thanks
Shashi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is resolved by adding skip-check new option after install

/opt/mapr-installer/bin/install --skip-checks new